# Replacing a variable by its value in a Select query

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios, sqlite

This is my case, i want to use NSString variable in a select query:

```
NSString *arrayThemeList=@"element1, element2, element3";
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                              @"SELECT * from table1 where type IN ?"];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];


        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, 
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [arrayThemeList UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

               //Do the rest work...
```

Obviously, i want to use the `arrayThemeList` into the query with the `bind` statement.

However, this seems not to be giving the wanted result, is there anything i am doing wrong?
Thanx in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

The IN clause should have the entries enclosed in brackets. Try:

```
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                          @"SELECT * from table1 where type IN ( ? )"];
```

Also, your strings need to be enclosed, so change the first line to be:

```
NSString *arrayThemeList=@"'element1', 'element2', 'element3'";
```

The resulting query should be:

```
SELECT * from table1 where type IN ( 'element1', 'element2', 'element3' )
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply :) unfortunately, i got nothing yet :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding variables to parts of an IN-list, you needs some parentheses around the IN-list, and you have to have one placeholder (question mark) for each separate value:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE type IN (?, ?, ?);
```

and then bind three separate values, one per placeholder.  There isn't a way (in most SQL DBMS; I think not in SQLite too) to bind a list of values to a single placeholder.

If you only get the data as a single string, then you will have to format the SQL before you prepare the statement, and you forego the the ability to reuse the prepared statement with different values, and you have to worry about [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327).  Also, if you are dealing with string values, you need to enclose each string in single quotes (and escape – by doubling up – any embedded single quotes).